# Large Matrix Multiplication using PDL - Perl

Tags: perl, matrix-multiplication, pdl, large-data

I need to generate (40000 x 20000) matrix via SQL and perform matrix operation like A'A. Then I need to obtain Eigen value and Eigen Vectors.

Can you suggest me ways to implement this in Perl.
(Maybe via [`PDL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL))

How can I multiply large matrix stored in file.?

Thank You

Comment: This looks a lot to me like you're trying to implement something like least squares fitting using a naive algorithm. PDL can do the operation you want, but perhaps you could describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. PDL may have a canned solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest PDL, you can assemble various pieces to achieve what you're aiming for:

- https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::IO::FastRaw#mapfraw to memory-map a disk file as a PDL ndarray, with no RAM limitations
- https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::IO::DBI to read from a DBI handle
- https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::LinearAlgebra to use LAPACK routines for various fast matrix operations including eigenvalues - make sure you either turn off PDL [auto-parallelism](https://metacpan.org/dist/PDL/view/Basic/Pod/ParallelCPU.pod) if you use a parallel LAPACK such as OpenBLAS

If David is right and you are actually aiming to do least-squares fitting, PDL::LinearAlgebra has routines for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

$PDL::BIGPDL=1;
$c = sequence(60000, 60000); ## you need 32gb of ram and about 75gb of swap to do this.

$c * $d is different then $c x $d in PDL 
I believe there are modules for Eigen value or Eigen vector
I have not used them yet tho...

Comment: If you're the same Mark Baker who created [this electron simulation](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=963819), it's just been incorporated in git `master`'s `demo 3dgal`, to be released soon!